# python: changing dictionary returned by groupdict()

Tags: python, object, mutable

Is it safe to modify a mutable object returned by a method of a standard library object?

Here's one specific example; but I'm looking for a general answer if possible.

```
#m is a MatchObject
#I know there's only one named group in the regex
#I want to retrieve the name and the value
g, v = m.groupdict().popitem()
#do something else with m
```

Is this code safe? I'm concerned that by changing groupdict() I'm corrupting the object m (which I still need for later).

I tested this out, and a subsequent call to m.groupdict() still returned the original dictionary; but for all I know this may be implementation-dependent.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that the answer is:

No, it's no safe. There's no promise from Python Standard Library that modifying m.groupdict() won't corrupt the MatchObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's only *guaranteed* to be safe if the documentation says so.  (In this particular case it seems very unlikely that another implementation would behave differently though.)

Comment: True. Other implementations *usually* follow what CPython does and CPython *usually* preserves compatibility with its own previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

`groupdict` returns a new dictionary every time:

```
In [20]: id(m.groupdict())
Out[20]: 3075475492L

In [21]: id(m.groupdict())
Out[21]: 3075473588L
```

I cannot speak about whole standard library though. You should check yourself, whether a method returns a reference to some internally stored structure inside the object or creates a new one every time it is called. `groupdict` creates a new one every time. This is why it should be safe to modify result dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, this helps.

However, I'm not sure how I would check what the method returns, other than by reading the implementation code. Of course, I don't want to rely on any specific implementation in deciding whether my code is safe.

Answer (score 0):

You should be safe in this particular case, because `MatchObject.groupdict()` returns a dictionary representing the matched groups, but it is a new copy every time.

[`dict.popitem()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) **does** change the dictionary you are calling it on though.

> Remove and return an arbitrary (key,
>   value) pair from the dictionary.
>
> `popitem()` is useful to **destructively**
>   iterate over a dictionary, as often
>   used in set algorithms. If the
>   dictionary is empty, calling
>   `popitem()` raises a `KeyError`.

Comment: How can I be certain that it is a new copy? I expect it's stated somewhere in Python documentation, but where

Comment: @max As far as I know all of [`MatchObject`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects)'s methods and properties return values only and thus you can't change the underlying object. I don't think this *has* to documented, since wouldn't make any sense that you could change the object.

Comment: @quantumSoup Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought in Python you can only return a reference - and a reference can be to an internal object or to a newly created object.

Comment: @max I meant that you can't change the underlying MatchObject

Comment: @quantumSoup hmm.. if MatchObject happens to expose any of its internal parts to you through a reference, you can modify them. And if MatchObject doesn't expect you to, you may corrupt it by this modification.

Comment: @max That's why it doesn't expose its internal parts.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different operations being performed on `m` here. The first, `groupdict`, creates a dictionary from `m`. The second, `popitem`, returns an item from the dictionary and modifies *the dictionary* (but not the underlying item).

So subsequent calls to `m.groupdict()` still *create* the dictionary from the same `m`.

But why are you using `popitem` at all? Why not just `items()`?

Comment: But how do I know that groupdict() actually creates a brand new dictionary every time I call it? I am afraid in some implementation it might provide a reference to an internal dictionary object. Is this clarified anywhere in the documentation?

Regarding your last point, of course I could easily switch to the non-destructive .items()[0]; I just wanted to give some simple example.